# Is there a generic swap method in the framework?

Tags: .net

Does a method like this exist anywhere in the framework?

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T left, ref T right) {
    T temp;
    temp = left;
    left = right;
    right = temp;
}
```

If not, any reason why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange.aspx).  This does it in a thread-safe, atomic call.

---

Edit after comments:

Just to clarify how this works using Interlocked.Exchange, you would do:

```
left = Interlocked.Exchange(ref right, left);
```

This will be the equivalent (in effect) to doing:

```
Swap(ref left, ref right);
```

However, Interlocked.Exchange does this as an atomic operation, so it's threadsafe.

Comment: Interlocked.Exchange sets a value, it doesn't actually swap values. You would still need to save a temp, and call Interlocked.Exchange twice, so you don't really gain anything.

Comment: Interlocked.Exchange is not really equivalent of the specified Swap. It only changes the first value and doesn't touch the second (itself).

Comment: @jrista: Why would you need to call it twice?  Interlocked.Exchange returns the ~original~ value, so you only need to call it once, and use the returned value.  See my edit.

Comment: @Reed: That's why I mentioned "itself," in my comment. As mentioned in the answer, it's also different due to atomic semantics that might have overhead...

Comment: It's misleading to say this is atomic, the assignment to `left` will happen after the assignment to `right`.

Answer (score 5):

No, the framework does not have such a method. Probably the reason is there's not much benefit to have it built-in and you could very easily (as you did) add it yourself. This also requires use of `ref` as parameter, which will greatly limit the use cases. For instance, you couldn't do this:

```
List<int> test; 
// ...
Swap(ref test[0], ref test[1]); // won't work, it's an indexer, not an array
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that C# does not have references to slots, so implementing such a method requires expression parameters, which is somewhat advanced stuff:

```
     static void Swap < Model, Value > (
         Func < Model, Value > getter,
         Action < Model, Value > setter,
         Model m1, Model m2
     ) {
         Value v = getter (
             m1
         ); setter (
             m1, getter (
                 m2
             )
         ); setter (
             m2, v
         );
     }
```

Of course, a quality implementation would check that things are unequal first.
You can even do away with a separate setter:

```
      static void Swap < Model, Value > (
         Expression < Func < Model, Value > > getter
         , Model m1, Model m2

     )
      {
         var valueParam = Expression .Parameter (
             typeof (
                 Value
             )
         ); Swap (
             getter .Compile (), Expression .Lambda < Action < Model, Value > > (
                 Expression .Assign (
                     getter .Body, valueParam
                 ), new [] {
                     getter .Parameters [
                         0X0
                     ], valueParam
                 }
             ) .Compile (), m1, m2
         );
     }
```