# My Swap Function Don't Work

Tags: c#

I want to discuss my problem clearly.
I have a function to Swap value of two variable

```
    public static void Swap<T>(ref T first, ref T second)
    {
        T temp = first;
        first = second;
        second = temp;
    }
```

I have use it in my code as this:

```
        Swap<DateTime>(ref TarikhePayaneGozaresh, ref TarikheShorooeGhozaresh);
```

I have checked it many times and now I am confused.
As you can see the value didn't swaped!

**Update** : I have write more of my code.

Comment: Any chance that a: you have multiple threads accessing this data, or b: there is a struct with explicit layout involved?

Comment: This is impossible given the information provided in the question. Please update with more details about how you're calling the function, what types you're using, whether you're accessing the fields from multiple threads, etc.

Comment: The swap function works fine, see [here](http://ideone.com/vo4Nj)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922505/is-there-a-generic-swap-method-in-the-framework

Comment: **This question has been finished here**

Comment: "The question has been finished here" What does that mean? Did you come up with a solution? How did you solve the problem? You should post an answer that explains the solution and how you figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The swap works fine:

```
var TarikhePayaneGozaresh = DateTime.Parse("9/9/2010 12:00:00 AM");
var TarikheShorooeGharardad = DateTime.Parse("9/9/1991 12:00:00 AM");
Swap<DateTime>(ref TarikhePayaneGozaresh, ref TarikheShorooeGharardad);
Console.WriteLine(TarikhePayaneGozaresh); // 09/09/1991 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(TarikheShorooeGharardad); //09/09/2010 00:00:00
```

I can only conclude that the problem is something outside of the code you have shown us, for example:

- confusing which fields/properties/variables TarikheShorooeGharardad and TarikhePayaneGozaresh refer to at each point (hit "show definition" to ensure they are the same)
- in the case of fields/properties, confusing which objects they relate to
- anything involving mutable structs (i.e. structs with values that can change after creation)... mutable structs are evil and will always cause confusion such as changes which seem to evaporate unexpectedly

  - or doubly so if it has explicit layout (unlikely, but even more evil if abused)

Comment: **This question has been finished here**

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly do you do the verification?

I notice that inside `CalculateMablagheDariaftieKol()` you Swap a ref with a non-ref parameter.

So outside `CalculateMablagheDariaftieKol()` you will not see a (complete) Swap.